# Is there an iOS KeyChain equivalent for Windows 8 [desktop] apps?

Tags: javascript, html, security, encryption, windows-8

I'm looking to create a Windows 8 desktop application using HTML5/JavaScript/CSS. I recently created an iOS mobile application, and to securely encrypt the data we retrieved a key from the iOS KeyChain to encrypt it on the mobile device. For a Windows 8 desktop application, I'm wondering if there's anything similar we can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the DataProtection APIs available on Windows platforms.
It provides you with methods to encrypt and decrypt data using a machine key. Note that this data is not portable to another machine.

You also want to make sure to create a backup of your machine key to prevent data loss (this is done automatically for you if you're joined to a AD domain).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229741(v=vs.85).aspx

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/309408/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0